# Understand & fix php session lost between https and http

Tags: php, session, ssl

I have developed a mvc site from scratch and locally it works, but what a surprise ! Trying the site uploaded to my hosting it doesn't work.

The login sequence is the following:
Every page checks if you are loged (http) and redirect to login page (https) if you don't.
Always you will be redirected to login page.

After some research, I have discovered the reason: php session is lost between https and http.

I don't understand why works locally and remotely not, but I think due php local settings set php sesssion identifier as PHPESSID for http & https and remote settings not.

Thinking about the trouble, I understand  I can fix the issue passing the session identifier from https to http or making the whole site https rewriting the urls as follow:

intranet.mysite.com/anypage/

Hosting shared ssl
https://server.subdomain/~user/public_html/intranet/anypage/

Additional information

the page is hosted under hostgator. The url paths are

site
intranet.mydomain.com

ssl shared access
https://gatorxxx.hostgator.com/~user/intranet

how I can make session works between urls ?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you host the SSL page on a different domain? The PHP session cookie is lost then, because the cookie is bound by subdomain (or domain, whichever the cookiedomain is set to).

Comment: The web is hosted under intranet subdomain as follow: intranet.mysite.com but I have to use server.domain.com/~user/intranet due I use shared ssl and I can`t use private ssl.

Comment: You could send the session id with the request params to the https / http envoirement and re-initialise the session there with something like session_id($_GET['session']);

There is just no way to use (session)cookies across different domains without exchanging this information with the requests made.